Would it be possible to infer the Merlyn-education-corpus-qa model on two RTX 4090 GPUs?
I am trying to run the Merlyn-education-corpus-qa model on my two RTX 4090 graphics cards. The code I am using is exactly the same as the one on the HuggingFace page for the model (https://huggingface.co/MerlynMind/merlyn-education-corpus-qa). The only change I've made to the code is adding the .half() to the model and the inputs:
model.half()
...
inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").half().to(device)

The problem is that the process ends with 'Killed'.
Is there any way to use not just one GPU but both of the ones I have? Perhaps using Accelerate or DeepSpeed libraries.
Edit:
The code I have used is as follows, where I make use of a single GPU:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
model_path = "MerlynMind/merlyn-education-corpus-qa"
device = torch.device("cuda:0") # change device id as necessary
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)    
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, fast_tokenizer=True)
model.half()
model.to(device) # move to device


https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.9.2/parallelism.html

"Killled" means it was killed by OOM Killer of the Linux Kernel, meaning you ran out of CPU memory, not GPU memory. How much CPU memory do you have, and you should always include code.
